# Select Query in laravel JSON field

Tags: json, laravel

Please i want some help,
I have database table that contains JSON field with data like 
[{"id":285,"quantity":1,"options":"[]"},{"id":305,"quantity":1,"options":"[]"}]
Then i want to select where this JSON of id = 285
I already tried many solutions but not one helped me 
Any help please 
Thanks.

Comment: doing that is not possible but you saving json data in each field and converting the entire row is poss so you might wanna save normal data instead of json data

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/making-a-laravel-54-query-on-a-json-field-containing-a-json-array?page=1

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 5.6.24, you can use [`whereJsonContains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#json-where-clauses):

```php
DB::table('table')->whereJsonContains('column', ['id' => 285])->get();
```

Before that, use M.Islam's suggestion:

```php
DB::table('table')->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(column, ?)', ['{"id": 285}'])->get();
```